# Where to place the tie/wrap when doing Gelilah

Tags: sefer-torah, mezuzah, hagbah-gelilah

We were taught as kids that when doing Gelilah (for an Ashkenazi Sefer Torah) that the tie/wrap around the Sefer Torah should be in the upper-third of the Sefer Torah similar to a Mezuzah should be in the upper-third of a doorway.  A Rabbi that I am no longer in contact with said that he found a source for this, but never told me where it was.

1. Does anyone know what the source is for the tie/wrap in the upper-third like a mezuzah?
2. I have seen other people say that is must at least be in the upper-half.  Is there a source for that?

Comment: I was doing glilah once in mean shearim and I had placed towards to the middle. But a old yerushalmi accosted me to put higher up

Answer (score 1):

http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=5655&CategoryID=1254

This Minhag is by no means universal. Minhag Chabad is to specifically wrap the belt around the lower third. The reason this is done so is that we compare it to the Gartel one wears between his heart and his lower body. The Sefer Torah has three parts, Head, Body, Foot. Another reason is that Moshe Rabeinu held the bottom third of the Luchos.

Those that specifically tie the belt on the top third base it on comparing it to a Mezuza. (Minhag Yisrael Torah 147:2)

> שם. צריך חיפוש מה המקור והטעם למנהגנו בגלילה, לקשור בתחילת שליש התחתון
>   דווקא (ספר-המנהגים ס"ע 15. וראה מה שנמסר ע"ז ב'כפר חב"ד' גיליון 762
>   עמ' 91, מקור ע"פ הירושלמי פ"ד דתענית ה"ה, שמרע"ה החזיק בשליש [התחתון
>   של] הלוחות, עיי"ש).
>
> למנהג העולם לקשור בתחילת שליש העליון, י"א שזהו ע"ד הדין בקביעת מזוזה
>   (יו"ד רפט ס"ב, ברכ"י שם, 'מנהג ישראל תורה' סי' קמז ס"ק ב).
>
> י"א שמנהגנו הוא ע"ד ההפסקה שנעשית בגוף האדם ע"י האבנט בין הלב לחלק
>   התחתון, וגם בס"ת יש ג' שלישים, ראש גוף ורגל. ויש לבדוק אם יש לזה
>   שייכות לג' שלישים דז"א, שהשליש התחתון שייך לגילוי למטה בדווקא (ראה
>   תו"א נח,ג).

I also found this in http://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/71_66_74.pdf which says that there is no Halachic source for this and the only source is Sefer Yalkot Avraham that it is a Minhag Sanz.

> ובענין מה שהקפידו לחגור בגלילה את האבנט בשליש העליון של הס"ת, איו לו
>   מקור בהלכה ומקורו היחיד הוא במנהגי צאנז שהובא בילקוט אברהם, וז"ל –
>   'אמר לי בעל הדרכי תשובה בשם הגה"ק מצאנז זצוק"ל, שצריכין לכרוך החגורה
>   סביב הס"ת שהוא גלילה, למעלה מחציו בתחילת השליש העליון, כמו במזוזה
>   דצריכין לקובעה בשליש העליון,

Comment: I find that Sifrei Torah tend to "bulge" and bend toward the side that has the most klaf. Realistically, doesn't it make sense to place the belt in the middle?

Comment: I know that some Chabad have this different custom, but I think it is exclusive to them (I have never seen it elsewhere).  I am interested in the reason for the predominant Ashkenazi customs.

Comment: @GershonGold: Would you consider separating out the different parts of your answer above?